# gfortran makefile problems

Tags: c++, makefile, fortran, static-libraries

I have program writing on fortran which uses library.
For compiling I use my simple shell script and everything is fine:

***gfortran*** -c mod_input.f90 mod_cpp.f90 mod_data.f90  main.f90 b_coils.f

***gfortran*** -o main mod_input.o mod_cpp.o mod_data.o  main.o b_coils.o libspline.a -lstdc++

(libspline.a - *library writing on c++*)

Now I want to use makefile instead of shell script, but don't know how to write it properly.

*Makefile:*

```
target = main
srcdir = src/
objdir = obj/
targetdir = run/

FORT = gfortran
mflag = module
FORTFLAGS =
LDFLAGS = -lstdc++  

MKLPATH =/home/gatto/Desktop/ray_u3/src
LIBDIR  =-L$(MKLPATH)
LIBS = -lspline                                                             
MODDIR = obj/                                                           

# Ray sources
sources = mod_input.f90 mod_cpp.f90 mod_data.f90  main.f90 b_coils.f


# objects
objects  = $(patsubst %.for,%.o,$(filter %for,$(sources)) )
objects += $(patsubst %.f90,%.o,$(filter %f90,$(sources)) )

# main target
build:$(targetdir)$(target)

# build rules
$(targetdir)$(target):$(addprefix $(objdir),$(objects))
    @echo === build $@ ===
    $(FORT) $(FORTFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBDIR) -o $@ $(LIBS) $^

#compilation target
compile :$(addprefix $(objdir),$(objects))

# compilation rules
$(objdir)%.o : $(srcdir)%.f90
    @echo === compile $< ===
    $(FORT) -c $(objdir) $(FORTFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(objdir)%.o : $(srcdir)%.f
    @echo === compile $< ===
    $(FORT) -c $(objdir) $(FORTFLAGS) -o $@ $<


# cleaning rules
cleanobj:
    -rm $(objdir)*.o $(objdir)*.mod
cleantarget:
    -rm $(targetdir)$(target)

cleanall:cleanobj cleantarget

.PHONY: compile build cleanall cleanobj cleantarget
```

*Output:*

```
gfortran  -lstdc++   -L/home/gatto/Desktop/ray_u3/src -o run/main -lspline obj/mod_input.o obj/mod_cpp.o obj/mod_data.o obj/main.o
obj/mod_data.o: In function `__global_data_MOD_modbfield':
mod_data.f90:(.text+0x3e2): undefined reference to `gbcoil_'
obj/mod_data.o: In function `__global_data_MOD_moddensity':
mod_data.f90:(.text+0x5d4): undefined reference to `GetSplineValue'
mod_data.f90:(.text+0x64f): undefined reference to `GetSplineValue'
mod_data.f90:(.text+0x6ca): undefined reference to `GetSplineValue'
mod_data.f90:(.text+0x745): undefined reference to `GetSplineValue'
obj/mod_data.o: In function `__global_data_MOD_inpfile':
mod_data.f90:(.text+0xa66): undefined reference to `Approx_input'
mod_data.f90:(.text+0xa75): undefined reference to `SetSpline'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [run/main] Error 1
```

Comment: Lets start with indentation, the commands for a rule needs to be indented by a single tab. When you fixed that come back and update the question to include the actual problem you have with the makefile. Like for example tell us what happens you try to use it. Include all output, complete and unedited.

Comment: You have a makefile snippet here which uses a large number of variables that aren't defined anywhere we can see. You need to show us a complete example and, as Joachim indicated, the commands you are running and the exact output/results you are getting.

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: Have you tried moving your `$^` before the `$(LIBS)`? Order matters when linking, so it may be as simple as that.

Comment: Why don't you follow a makefile tutorial if you are new to makefiles? for example http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/ or http://www.cs.usask.ca/staff/oster/makefiles.html or google for more convenient tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `automake` (and `autoconf`). It do have a large number of `metatag`s, but for simple programs, its faster to write, and in most of the cases, you may find yourself get going with minimal changes (like `filename`).

Here is my `autoconf` and `automake`'s input for a similar project, which just uses `lapack`, instead of `mkl`.

**configure.ac**

```
#AC_PREREQ(2.69)
AC_INIT([src], [0.1],
    [],
    [mftc],
    [])
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build-aux])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])

AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.9.6 dist-bzip2 subdir-objects foreign])

AC_SEARCH_LIBS([dsyev_], [lapack], ,AC_MSG_ERROR([No LAPACK library]))
AC_OPENMP
FCFLAGS="$OPENMP_FFLAGS "
AC_PROG_FC([gfortran, ifort])
AC_CHECK_PROG([DEPF90_CHECK],[makedepf90],[yes],[no])
AM_CONDITIONAL([FOUND_MAKEDEPF90], [test "x$DEPF90_CHECK" = xyes])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
         Makefile
         ])
AC_OUTPUT
```

**Makefile.am**

```
bin_PROGRAMS =  mftc
mftc_SOURCES = src/mftc.f90  src/parse.f90 src/sort.f90
depend depend.mk:
    makedepf90 $(mftc_SOURCES) >depend.mk
@am__include@ @am__quote@depend.mk@am__quote@
mftc_LDADD = 
EXTRA_DIST=depend.mk autogen.sh Makefile.am
CLEANFILES =*.mod  *.log
```

The `depend depend.mk` depends on `makedepf90` program, which is available on most linux platform. This program take care of the dependencies (that is modules are compiled first before the program).

**Usage** 
If you are ok with LAPACK, I don't see anything for you to change in  the configure.ac. Change _SOURCES line for proper filename.
 Now, its 3 command in terminal:

```
 $autoconf 
 $./configure 
 $make
```

Off course, you also need to have automake and autoconf installed.

Hope, this helps